# boundedness of $\{\int_E(g f_n)\}$ implies boundedness of $\{f_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I need some help on this problem:

> Let $E$ be a measurable set, $1 \le p < \infty$ and $q$ is the conjugate of $p$. Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence in $L^p(E)$ such that for each $g \in L^q(E)$ the sequence $\{\int_E(g  f_n)\}$ is bounded. Show that $\{f_n\}$ is bounded.

Comment: Use the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem.

Comment: thanx for the help but I do not see the connection!!! my issue is the sequence $\{\int_E(g  f_n)\}$ we know from Riesz Representation theorem $\int_E(g \cdot f) = T(f)$ where T is a linear fnctional, but how to introduce $f_n$ to get the sequence.

Comment: I think it will have to do with the weak convergence. but I just can't see the connection!